# How can I preserve the aspect ratio of internal elements of an SVG while allowing the SVG itself to scale?

Tags: html, svg

I'm very new to SVG, so I apologize if this is an obvious question. I've tinkered for a few hours and seem to have hit a wall.

I am attempting to create an SVG element in an HTML document which:

- has a firm boundary on the outer viewport
- preserves the aspect ratio of internal elements
- does not preserve the aspect ratio of the outer SVG element
- can be resized arbitrarily while maintaining these contraints

This JSFiddle illustrates what I mean and what I have attempted:

http://jsfiddle.net/a8q6S/

And here's the same code since I can't post this otherwise:

```
<div>
     <h2>correct placement and aspect ratio, but cannot be resized without losing relative placement</h2>

    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid red;">
        <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="10"></circle>
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="10"></circle>
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="10"></circle>
    </svg>
</div>
<div>
     <h2>correct aspect ratio of circle, incorrect relative placement</h2>

    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin" style="width: 200px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid red;">
        <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="10"></circle>
        <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="10"></circle>
        <circle cx="100%" cy="100%" r="10"></circle>
    </svg>
</div>
<div>
     <h2>correct relative placement, can be resized, but loses internal aspect ratio</h2>

    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="width: 200px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid red;">
        <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="10"></circle>
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="10"></circle>
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="10"></circle>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Is this possible? Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve what you want using pure SVG.  You will need to use some javascript to tweak the SVG a bit on load and resize.

If you use something like your second example, you will only need to tweak the viewBox, width and height.  The contents can stay constant.

For example,

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid red;">
    <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="10"></circle>
    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="10"></circle>
    <circle cx="100%" cy="100%" r="10"></circle>
</svg>
```

would become

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 100" style="width: 200px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid red;">
    <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="10"></circle>
    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="10"></circle>
    <circle cx="100%" cy="100%" r="10"></circle>
</svg>
```

when the width doubled.

http://jsfiddle.net/a8q6S/3/

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use 2 svg, one with preserveAspectRatio="none" and the other one without. The last one will be the upper one.

In my example, I draw an arrow with 100% height, and then I draw circles on it.

```
<body style="height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; background-color: grey">
<svg style="height: 100%; width: 10%; left: 10%; position: absolute; overflow: hidden;"
    viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <rect x="40" y="0" r="40"  width="20" height="95%" style="fill:blue;"/>
    <polygon points="40,95 50,100 60,95" style="fill:blue;" />
</svg>
<svg style="height: 100%; width: 10%; left: 10%; position: absolute; overflow: hidden;">
    <circle cx="50%" cy="16.6%" r="25" style="fill:white;" />
    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50" style="fill:white;" />
    <circle cx="50%" cy="83.3%" r="25" style="fill:white;" />
</svg>
</body>
```

Answer (score -2):

<strike>Thank you. I was having a similar issue. This is my solution.</strike>

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100% 100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin" style="width: 200px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid red;">
    <circle cx="0%" cy="0%" r="10"></circle>
    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="10"></circle>
    <circle cx="100%" cy="100%" r="10"></circle>
</svg>
```

Sorry I'm also new with svgs, thanks for the corrections.

This doesn't directly solve the problem presented, but I found that I couldn't preserve the aspect ratio of a viewbox inside a viewbox that does not preserve aspect ratio.

The caveat to this solution is that you must establish the width and height for each inner svg unless doesn't preserve relative placement.

If you want to preserve both relative placement and aspect ratio, do not use a viewbox.

```
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin" width=200 height=100 style="border: 1px solid red;">
   <svg>
     <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="10"></circle>
     <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="10"></circle>
     <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="10"></circle>
   </svg>
   <svg viewbox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none" fill=blue width=200 height=100>
     <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="7"></circle>
     <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="7"></circle>
     <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="7"></circle>
   </svg>
   <svg  fill=red width=200 height=100>
     <circle cx="0%" cy="0%" r="4"></circle>
     <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="4"></circle>
     <circle cx="100%" cy="100%" r="4"></circle>
   </svg>
 </svg>
```

Comment: Could you explain?

Comment: I don't see how this answer the OPs question.  Also the `viewBox` here is invalid. You cannot use percentage values in a `viewBox`.